# Login screen - Unfortunately Stack Exchange has stopped

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

[image]

**Steps to Reproduce issue:**

1. Log out from the app (if you are logged in)
2. Make sure Internet connection is OFF
3. Load App
4. Click on 'Log in using Facebook' and it will show you accounts list (if multiple accounts) to sign in with.
5. Select any account and get crash message.

**Current app version:** 0.1.45

Comment: I have to hand it to you. You've been keeping the dev's honest with the unavailable internet connection force closes.

Comment: @StevenV he he he...but I am surprised to see unavailable internet connection. Recently I have found some issues again which were resolved and marked as status-completed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of version 0.1.46 coming out later tonight we won't let you attempt to login if you don't have any network connection at all.

As a sidenote: Thanks for the reports :) Please keep on reporting any network issues if you spot them since that's one of the things we don't test much internally.

[image]

Comment: Yes its resolved in build 0.1.46.